# MySQL - path from Community (free) version 5.6.31 to Enterprise

Tags: mysql, enterprise

Full disclosure.  I have never upgraded a database.  I have a MySQL Community that is not the latest @5.6.31 ( latest is 8 ?) to the paid, Enterprise version.  We will ask Tech Support once purchase of Enterprise is fully approved... but really trying to find a clear upgrade path online has proven difficult.  I'm a novice, so feel free to be very details in replies.

Thanks

Comment: Voted to migrate this question to the [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site of the network. You'll certainly get quality answers there.

Comment: thanks.  I didn't know there was a DBA site.  I'll copy over there...